# How can I stop net toast show?

Tags: android, show, toast

I making a simple example like sign up program, where I have want two type condition "not null" or equal to. Here equal to is working but when I run this program all toast show after previous toast.

Here is my code,

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (name.getText().toString().equals("")){
                Toast tname = Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Please Enter Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                tname.show();}
            if (email.getText().toString().equals("")){
                Toast temail = Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Please Enter Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                temail.show();}
            if (user.getText().toString().equals("")){
                Toast tuser = Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Please Enter username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                tuser.show();}
            if (pass.getText().toString().equals("")){
                Toast tpass = Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Please Enter password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                tpass.show();}
            if (pass2.getText().toString().equals("")){
                Toast tpass2 = Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Please Re-Enter Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                tpass2.show();}
            if(pass.getText().toString().equals(pass2.getText().toString()))
            {
                db.insertData(sname, semail, suser, spass);

                name.setText("");
                email.setText("");
                user.setText("");
                pass.setText("");
                pass2.setText("");

                Toast succ = Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Data Inserted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                succ.show();

            }else
            {
                Toast error = Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Password didn't match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                error.show();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: use else if statement instead of multiple if statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :-

```
 if (!(etEmail.getText().toString().matches(emailPattern))) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not valid email address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;

                } else if (etPassword.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 6) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Lenght must be Greater then 6 character", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Either do:

```
if (name.getText().toString().equals("")){
    Toast tname = Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Please Enter Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    tname.show();}
else if (email.getText().toString().equals("")){
    Toast temail = Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Please Enter Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    temail.show();}
```

`else` is a keywork here
The first error message only will be shown.

Or if you would like to show all error messages at once, you can create one message from all, do something like:

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
if (name.getText().toString().equals("")){
    text.append("Please Enter Name");}
if (email.getText().toString().equals("")){
    text.append("Please Enter Email");}
// other conditions here
Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, text.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```html
if (name.getText().toString().equals("")){
                Toast tname = Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Please Enter Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                tname.show();}
            if (email.getText().toString().equals("")){
                Toast temail = Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Please Enter Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                temail.show();}
            else if (user.getText().toString().equals("")){
                Toast tuser = Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Please Enter username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                tuser.show();}
            else if (pass.getText().toString().equals("")){
                Toast tpass = Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Please Enter password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                tpass.show();}
            else if (pass2.getText().toString().equals("")){
                Toast tpass2 = Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Please Re-Enter Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                tpass2.show();}
            else if(pass.getText().toString().equals(pass2.getText().toString()))
            {
                db.insertData(sname, semail, suser, spass);

                name.setText("");
                email.setText("");
                user.setText("");
                pass.setText("");
                pass2.setText("");

                Toast succ = Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Data Inserted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                succ.show();

            }else
            {
                Toast error = Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Password didn't match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                error.show();
            }
```

This is basically just adding an `else if` which will group the statements rather than starting a new if statement for every action.

Hope this helps!